# my Python program shut down when i executing by double click

Tags: python, shutdown

i write some python program.

i usually execute my program by CMD

but this time, i tried to execute program by double click

it works well until interpreter meet input code.

when i input some texts,  it shut down

my input code is

```
for i in (input('range input => ')).split(' '):
    range_list.append(int(i));
```

it works totally well when i execute by path(py ~.py) through the CMD

can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

The interpreter is running in an endless loop.  Executing your program from windows or via the command line using python will run and exit the program immediately.

At the end of your program just add

```
input()
```

This will keep it open so you can see your results.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah when the program is done, it closes.
You can add something like `x = input()` at the end if you want to keep it open, or just run it in cmd.

Answer (score 2):

Your program opens in a windowed mode when you double click it. The window will disappear / close down when the program finishes, which happens a lot fast after you have entered all the required inputs.

If you wish to see the output before the program exit, expect an `input` at the end of your program.